# Java - user input/ arrays

Tags: java, arrays

So i'm having a hard time, finding ways on how to put integers inside the array, my objective is, make a program that a user will store 10 numbers and then after that display it.

So this is what I've done so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class wtf {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array[] = new int[10];

        for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            array[] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately there is an error.

Comment: array[] is wrong , you have to metion which index. array[i]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you need to specify an index for the integer array object...
every element of the array has its specific index... starting from **0 to n-1** where n is the number of elements in the array..
second of all, the index in programming always starts from 0 
Index is often confused with position..
Position has its usual meaning starting from 1...
consider an array having elements as 
56 98 65 12

here 98 is at index 1 and at position 2

all u need to do now is

change the input line to:

```
array[i]=input.nextInt();
```

Comment: `the index in programming always starts from 0 Index` - this is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to specify the index of where you want to insert the data

which in you case would be

```
 array[i - 1] = input.nextInt();
```

As arrays are zero based it would be better to loop like

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add elements to array, you just override existing ones.
So you need to provide the index where to put the element.

You should change a line:

```
        array[i-1] = input.nextInt();
```

`i-1` because arrays are indexed from `0` in java, and your fors `i` is from `1` to `10`.

More over you are iterating between 1 and 9 (`i = 1`, `i < array.length`), you should use code below to iterate between 1 and 10:

```
for(int i=1;i<=array.length;i++){
```

So basically you should use one of the blocks below:

#### 1-indexed

```
for(int i=1;i<=array.length;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    array[i-1] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

#### 0-indexed

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    array[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use a collection, e.g. `ArrayList` in this case you wouldn't need to provide up front the size of it.

Comment: Thank you very much, now i know how to index arrays properly :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the index when you access the array.

What you need is:

```
// You should also start from i = 0
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");

    // need array[i] here
    array[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

If you want to display the number after, you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```